# Why am I getting a 401 error when trying to access a running plain vanilla (unmodified) Web API app from Postman?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, controller, asp.net-web-api-routing, http-status-code-401, postman

I'm refreshing my Web API knowledge by reading ASP.NET Web API Succinctly. It has a simple example of using Postman to get some of the app's predefined data, entering the following into Postman using the Get verb:

```
http://localhost:52194/api/values
```

The Web API is running, and shows "*http://localhost:52194/*" in my (Chrome) browser.

Sending the above Get verbed URL from Postman, though, results in a "401 Unauthorized" in Postman.

Theoretically, I should see:

```
[
    "value1",
    "value2"
]
```

...because of this code existing in the app:

```
namespace PlatypusWebReports.Controllers
{
    [Authorize]
    public class ValuesController : ApiController
    {
        // GET api/values
        public IEnumerable<string> Get()
        {
            return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
        }
        . . .
```

Why am I getting a "401" and how can I prevent it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have this error because you marked your controller class with Authorize attribute. Just remove this attribute if you really don't need authorization for this API.

Comment: Ah, so the default authorization scheme of the template changed (to stricter) since the Succinctly book was written. The book does not show that directive, but the file had it before I commented it out, and now it does indeed work fine.